PostgreSQL - Extract Value Between First Set of Parenthesis
Consider a string like Ana (16) and Brian (14) are my children.
How to get the value of the first parenthesis? ('16' in this case.)
I tried with substring('Ana (16) and Brian (14) are my children.' from '\((.+)\)')
But it gives wrong result as 16) and Brian (14. (I can get it through strpos and substring combination. But need a better solution with regexp.)

It's important when asking for help that instead of saying "it gives wrong results" that you actually include the wrong results. That's a key part of debugging, to see the wrong results. It gives important clues as to what is wrong.

Hi @AndyLester, yes. It is given in the question now.

Your regex is almost correct, you just need to use non-greedy repetition to match the shortest string: +? instead of just +:
# select substring('Ana (16) and Brian (14) are my children.' from '\((.+?)\)');
 substring
-----------
 16
(1 row)


I like to use the regex functions, like regexp_matches. This one works:
SELECT (regexp_matches('Ana (16) and Brian (14) are my children.', '\(([^)]+)\)'))[1];

